# WCF service client initialisation strategy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have desktop application, that uses WCF services. I have got great usability improve when I implemented async WCF calls.

My question is: what is the best practice to initialize service client?

In previous realization there was single static object with credentials and a public method `GetClient()`, that was creating `new ServiceClient` before every call. In application there was commonly used such construction:

```
using (var svc = ServiceClientFactory.GetClient()) {
    var data = svc.CallMethod(...);
    some_application_context.specific_attribute = data;
}
```

so, before any call, was created new client, that was destroyed immediately after operation was finished and received data was used.

My question is: is it the best practice to call client constructor before every call?

I've tried to create single static client object, that is initialized once at startup and destroyed once on application closing, but I haven't got any notional performance gain.

Seems like it works fine, but I wonder if there any not very obvious obstacles in using single client? And what is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of a broad question, it depens on a lot of factors and also on style I guess.

When using reliable sessions or sessions in general you have to store the reference of course.
When calling the service many times it might be better to store the reference, or it might not. Better profile it then and there.

I always store a reference and create a property which check if the client is null or in the Faulted State.

```
Service.ServiceClient ShippingService
{
    get
    {
      if (mService == null || mService.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
      {
        mService = new Service.ServiceClient("netTcpService");
        mShippingService.Open();
      }

      return mService;
    }
}
```

Comment: `mService.State` - that was the obstacles, I was asking for

Answer (score 0):

You should look at dependency injection for getting your service references. Effectively it would be similar if not the same performance to what your doing now but it would make long term management easier and allow easier unit testing.

Most of the WCF overhead is connection negotiation so singleton vs new on each call won't really end up making a huge difference.